# Tensorflow 2.0 - keras training

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

Sorry for the beginner question as I've just started to pick up `Tensorflow`; Their 2.0 version seems to be a leap in development.

I've followed the tutorial from [this site](https://towardsdatascience.com/easy-image-classification-with-tensorflow-2-0-f734fee52d13), which returns the following result:
[image]

which is quite different from the site:
[image]

Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/sooonism/a7747b0c6aefdfa30abe59441cfb7f9f).

I practically copied and pasted the code from the site, but somehow the result is still so different.

The way I read my graph, there is practically no learning at all.

1. What causes this kind of scenario?
2. How do people normally tackle this kind of scenario?

Comment: your gist is unreachable

Comment: think i found the right gist updated the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## That is because you make a mistake in this line：

```
steps_per_epoch = round(BATCH_SIZE) // BATCH_SIZE
```

## It should be:

```
steps_per_epoch = num_train//BATCH_SIZE   # There is no need to use the round() function.
```

This is the [original code](https://github.com/cameroncruz/notebooks/blob/master/Easy_Image_Classification_with_TF_2.ipynb).